# Flutter cutting widget / hiding widget behind other widget

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I have this:

[image]

And I want to do this:

[image]

I find out that I have 2 ways to do this:

- Cutting my circle widget on bottom by some pixels
- Hide circle widget behind `bottomnavigationbar` (*preferred*)

Well, I don't know how to implement code in any of these 2 ways.

My code:

```
return Scaffold(
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
  floatingActionButton: FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
      child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 55),
          width: 80,
          height: 80,
          child: SizedBox(
              height: 80,
              child: SpeedDial(
                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                  overlayColor: Colors.white10,
                  elevation: 0,
                  backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 105, 30, 0),
                  childrenButtonSize: (const Size.square(100)),
                  direction: SpeedDialDirection.left,
                  child: const Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    size: 48,
                  ),
                  children: [
                    SpeedDialChild(
                        backgroundColor:
                            const Color.fromARGB(190, 105, 30, 1),
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.ac_unit_sharp,
                          size: 40,
                        ))
                  ])))),
  bottomNavigationBar: Container(
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(top: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2))),
    child: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Znajomi',
            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(190, 105, 30, 1),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.map),
            label: 'Mapa',
            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(210, 105, 30, 1),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.crown),
            label: 'Ranking',
            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(190, 105, 30, 1),
          ),
        ],
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        iconSize: 38,
        onTap: _onItemTap,
        elevation: 0),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Stack widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) for overlaying widgets on top of each other. If you place your BottomNavigationBar above your circle widget in the Stack the circle widget will be hidden behind the BottomNavigationBar.

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    FittedBox(),
    BottomNavigationBar(),
  ],
)
```

Example here with Containers:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    Container(
      width: 90,
      height: 90,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    Container(
      width: 80,
      height: 80,
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
  ],
)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes i know how Stack works but bottomNavigationBar and floatingActionButton are parameters of Scaffold and because of that i dont know how to implement it.

Comment: Is it necessary to have it FAB? if not then go with a custom designed button that looks like FAB and implement suggested above.

Comment: It is necessary

Comment: Okey it's not but then I don't know how to do bottomNavBar

Comment: This Scaffold is ruining everything because I must to use parameters like bottomnavzar